# removetags returns invalid filter

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Im trying to use `{{ content|removetags:"style link script"|safe }}` to remove specific html tags, but it is returning error `django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'removetags'` can someone help?

Comment: What django version are you using?

Comment: I am using Django 4.1

Comment: I think `removetags` has been deprecated. Can you try `striptags`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: I need a way to remove just a few specific tags, is there a way to do this?